# Call from Intel XDK not working

Tags: intel-xdk

What is the code to call from an application built on intel XDK? or that the way to do this?. I try different ways with no luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the solution is to add the whitelist to the build in this case tel:* or mailto:* if u want to send mails

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="tel:xxx-xxx-xxxx">Call</a>
```

replace xxx-xxx-xxxx with phone number to call

Comment: when i do tath in the emulator open skype but it do nothhing in my phone or others phones